# Interpreting lvalue and rvalue with notation arr+4 and arr++

Tags: c

```
   int arr[5];

   arr++;                                                        
   arr+4;                  //compile with only this 
   printf("%u", arr);
```

Why is the C language compiler not able to compile with `arr++` saying "lvalue required" but can
compile successfully with `arr+4`?  What is the lvalue concept with `arr++` notation?

Comment: `arr` is ultimately not an lvalue (since it's the result of decay), and you can only use the modifying increment operators on lvalues. There's no such restriction on addition (e.g. it's valid to say `1 + 1`).

Comment: post an entire program that others can compile and test.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is an array name a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer)

Answer (score 3):

When you use `arr` it can naturally *decay* to a pointer to its first element, i.e. it's equivalent to `&arr[0]`.

When you do `arr++` you attempt to modify this pointer (effectively doing `arr = arr + 1`). This is not possible, since the location of the array is fixed and can not be modified.

With `arr + 4` you're doing *pointer arithmetic*. Here you add `4` to the decayed pointer, but you do not attempt to modify the pointer itself. This is equal to `&arr[4]` in fact.

---

There is another small problem in the code you show. I say small but I mean *big*.

With

```
printf("%u", arr);
```

you let the array decay to a pointer. Then you attempt to print this pointer using the `"%u"` format specifier. *But* that format specifier is to print `int`, not pointers. Mismatching format specifier and argument types leads to *undefined behavior*.

To pint a generic (`void *`) pointer you need to use the `"%p"` format, and cast the pointer to `void *`:

```
printf("%p", (void *) arr);
```

Comment: actually `arr+4;` does nothing. Is syntacticaly correct but it is a statement with no effect and will just be ignored

Comment: Thanks .I got it.Nice explanation.